# Is it possible to bring options of <select> tag above it

Tags: html, css

In HTML `<select>` tag, drop-down div (of options) appear below the `<select>` tag by default. Is it at all possible of bringing options of `<select>` tag above it?

Currently I am creating another div on click but that's not the real solution.

I was wondering if there is any css option for doing this using only `<select>` tag instead of creating separate div.

Comment: Take a look at jQueries `chosen` replacement for classical `select` elements. They can be styles freely as opposed to the builtin variants.

Comment: No, implementation of <select> is left to brwoser (so absolutely no control over it). You should use something else (if you really need to theme it).

Comment: Please specify what you acually need. Do you want to create associate drop down ?

Comment: @Adriano what else can i use?

Comment: @OlivierH That's exactly what i am doing at the moment, creating a separate div

Comment: @chiragNandwani I just want options to appear above the select tag, that's it

Comment: I can't suggest best plug-in for that, actually some lack of one feature, the other is too heavy, another one bla bla bla. Take a look to comboboxes for jquery plugins and you'll find a lot of them.

Comment: @Adriano so there's no real alternative for <select> within html itself?

Comment: HTML alone? No but if you add some JavaScript then you're there. You can write it by your own or to use an existing plug-in.

Comment: well i am doing it atm, like i said i am creating a div on click of select, it looks exactly like select tag, but like i said in the question, i was trying to do it just using css. too bad it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no css property to do it. 
You will have to use Javascript librairies (or your own) to dynamically create a div, which will contain your options and display above the select input. 
You can have a look at [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) OR [Dojo Combobox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox.html) for example.

You will be able to theme the output and to display the options where you want, by adapting the code or modifying css properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in **`css`** property to do *drop-up* functionality.  If you're interested lots of `jQuery` plugins available to customize the `select` tag.

Check this [**example**](http://comp345.awardspace.com/superfish/superfish.html) and its [**source code**](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-multi-tiered-drop-up-menu.html).